# I have unlimited data and have "cellular data" turned on in both podcasts app and cellular- still won't download new podcasts

Tags: cellular-data, podcasts.app

This seems similar to other questions I've seen, but in other ones, as far as I can understand, it seems that people are trying to download podcasts while avoiding using data. This is not a concern for me as I have unlimited data, but the podcasts still won't download.

As the following screenshots show, I believe I have cellular data turned on everywhere and good reception, but podcasts still won't download over the cellular network. The internet is working for me otherwise, and I have tried resetting my network settings.

[image]

Comment: did you try accessing it true iTunes ?

Comment: I haven't. The reason that I can't do it (or at least it'd be inconvenient) is because I usually am at the office when I want to download these, and I cannot download iTunes onto my work computer. And since I want to listen to things on the way home (i.e. things that come out during the work day) using iTunes doesn't seem like a viable strategy.

Comment: ok, so where does your podcast comes from ?

Comment: i go into the podcast app and try to download it from there. screenshot below.                                       update: i can't add a screenshot. but that's how i download them. it's what i always used to do and it worked fine.

Comment: Actually wanted to have you check your podcast subscription, and make you aware the there is a limit of 100 meg set for cellular data. In office you use your office network that could prevent the downloads.